# Best practice for Mezzanine Site/Theme-Specific settings

Tags: django, mezzanine

There are several settings in my multi-themed/multi-site Mezzanine project that would be best served by independent (per theme) settings - items like BLOG_SLUG or GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE, for example. What is the best way to accomplish this in Mezzanine?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set different settings for each app (theme) you need to create a **defaults.py** file inside your app folder (`my_project/app/defaults.py`).

Then you can use `TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS` to hook the registered setting you created.

```
from mezzanine.conf import register_setting

register_setting(
    name="TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS",
    description=("Sequence of setting names available within templates."),
    editable=True,
    default=("BLOG_SLOG_2",
             ),
    append=True,
)

register_setting(
    name="BLOG_SLOG_2",
    label="Blog Slug",
    description="The blog slug for theme 2.",
    editable=True,
    default="Default Blog Slug",
)
```

You can read more about it from their official documentation: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html